# No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my ionic1 project in an emulator but I get the message shown in the title. This is very weird. This is what I have in my system.

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3

System:

Node : v6.11.1
npm  : 3.10.10 
OS   : macOS Sierra
```

Everything is installed as they should be.

**config.xml**

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Device">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="SplashScreen">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="StatusBar">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.statusbar.StatusBar" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Whitelist">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Keyboard">
            <param name="android-package" value="io.ionic.keyboard.IonicKeyboard" />
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <name>MyApp</name>
        <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
        <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
        <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
        <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    </widget>
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 7):

For some reasons probably this line not added in your config.xml (this is for android) :

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
```

Add something like this depended on your platform and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing platform and then add it again.

Comment: That didn't do the job either.